# Excel Macro set range.address

Tags: excel, vba

This code will have a pop window ask for a range.
I am trying to set a fix range.
I tried the following but non of them are working

```
Set WorkRng.Address = Shee1.Range(A1, O300)   
Set WorkRng = Shee1.Range(A1, O300)
```

Original code:

```
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng.Address = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(A1, O300
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection`
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
xStr = Application.InputBox("Text", xTitleId, "", Type:=2)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = WorkRng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set xRow = WorkRng.Rows(i)
    Set rng = xRow.Find(xStr, LookIn:=xlValues)
If rng Is Nothing Then
       xRow.Delete
    End If
```

Comment: when using `Range` the arguments are strings, So then need to be in quotes:  `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:O300")`

Answer (score -1):

```
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = ActiveSheet.Range("E1:E800")
```